# Alerting Wrong Value Slider Output

Tags: javascript, html

I have a slider that alerts the output on a button click, but it always alerts 2, when it should alert 1, 2, 3, or 4. Here's my code:

```js
var chanceoflive3;
var inputElement = document.querySelector('.range-input');
  var submitElement = document.querySelector('.submit');

  submitElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHTML = (chanceoflive3||0);
    localStorage.setItem("chanceoflive3", chanceoflive3);
  });

  inputElement.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var rangeValue = parseInt(this.value);
    chanceoflive3 = (chanceoflive3 || 0);

    if (rangeValue == 1) {
      chanceoflive3 = 1;
    }

    else if (rangeValue > 1 && rangeValue < 51 ) {
       chanceoflive3 = 2;
    }

    else if (rangeValue > 50 && rangeValue < 100) {
       chanceoflive3 = 3;
    }

     else if (rangeValue == 100) {
       chanceoflive3 = 4;
     }
    }
  );

  function handleClick(){
    alert(chanceoflive3);
  }
```

```html
<main>
    <form oninput="output.value = Math.round(range.valueAsNumber / 1)">
      <h2>
          Choose the Length of Your House
        </h2>
      <div class="range">
        <input name="range" type="range" min="1" max="100" class="range-input">
        <div class="range-output">
          <output id="output" class="output" name="output" for="range">
            50
          </output>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>

    <div class="wrapper">
    <button align=center onclick="handleClick()">
      <canvas width="200" height="50" id="canvas" align=center></canvas>
      <hover></hover>
      <span id="submit">SUBMIT</span>
    </button>
    </div>
```

It should alert 1 if the slider is set to 1, alert 2 if the slider is between 2 and 50, alert 3 if the slider is between 51 and 99, and 4 if it is set to 100. Although, it alerts 2, no matter what. Why, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you failing to set `chanceoflive3` beforehand, or did you simply choose not to include it in this snippet? It won't work if you haven't set it first, thanks to scoping.

Comment: Another note: Your submit button has an *id* of submit, and yet you're selecting `.submit` (a class selector) instead of `#submit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <form oninput="output.value = Math.round(range.valueAsNumber / 1)">
            <h2>
                Choose the Length of Your House
            </h2>
            <div class="range">
                <input name="range" type="range" min="1" max="100" class="range-input">
                <div class="range-output">
                    <output id="output" class="output" name="output" for="range">
                        50
                    </output>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </main>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <button align=center onclick="handleClick()">
            <canvas width="200" height="50" id="canvas" align=center></canvas>
            <hover></hover>
            <span id="submit">SUBMIT</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var inputElement = document.querySelector('.range-input');
        var submitElement = document.querySelector('#submit');
        var chanceoflive3 = chanceoflive3 || 0;

        submitElement.addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHTML = (chanceoflive3 || 0);
            localStorage.setItem("chanceoflive3", chanceoflive3);
        });

        inputElement.addEventListener('change', function () {
            var rangeValue = parseInt(this.value);

            if (rangeValue == 1) {
                chanceoflive3 = 1;
            }

            else if (rangeValue > 1 && rangeValue < 51) {
                chanceoflive3 = 2;
            }

            else if (rangeValue > 50 && rangeValue < 100) {
                chanceoflive3 = 3;
            }

            else if (rangeValue == 100) {
                chanceoflive3 = 4;
            }
        });

    function handleClick() {
        alert(chanceoflive3);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I would of never figured that out! I'll mark it as my answer!

Comment: `var chanceoflive3 = chanceoflive3 || 0;` ... really? that's just `var chanceoflive3 = 0;` ... also, a few words explaining the difference would help others perhaps ... your code is 99.9% identical to the question, so it shouldn't be too hard to explain

Comment: Would've probably been better to suggest scrapping the change event entirely and putting it in the click event.

Comment: thanks @JaromandaX, Ethan McTague, my intention was to keep the code of question as original as possible :)